# Anime with gems linked to different animals, each one having a superpower; one antagonist rides a robot spider

Tags: story-identification, anime

I remember that a guy with a girl I think travel to collect gems on his arm and in those gems it has animals and every animal has a different superpower...

I remember also that there's an evil guy who rides a robot spider or something like that and other girl with him and they used to run away with airship.

It has been 3 years.

Comment: We need more specific information in order to help you.  You say it has been 3 years: since it was made, or since you saw it?  Can you tell us more about the plot?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Anime where the guy has gems on his arm that indicates his power level?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/188680/)?

Comment: @RemyLebeau gotta wait for an acceptance of sorts (checkmark or "yep thank you" comment) to close dupes. Just in case you didn't know :)

Comment: @Jenayah yes, I'm aware of that. Doesn't mean the OP cant look at it and see if the suggested anime sounds familiar

Comment: @RemyLebeau I had the timestamps wrong it seems, you posted that before the answer. Sorry if I sounded preachy!

Answer (score 3):

Could you be thinking of [Magi Nation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magi-Nation_(TV_series))?

[image]

The three main characters all have gems that contain animals ("dream creatures"), each with their own abilities. The guy on the right seems to keep his gem(s) [in his gloves](https://youtu.be/WNxyFcizS1Q?t=20m14s). I don't know if there was an episode with a spider but the [episode I just linked to](https://youtu.be/WNxyFcizS1Q) has a [giant water strider](http://magination.wikia.com/wiki/Ocean_Strider).